# вызов функции копирования файла из public void onCreate

Tags: java, android-sdk

Понадобилось копировать некоторые файлы из внутреней памяти в память приложения при запуске. Нашёл функцию для копирования эти самых файлов и попытался её вызвать из public void onCreate но компилятор выдал ошибку Unhandled exception type IOException. Так вот я не знаю, как вызывать собственно говоря эту функцию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вызывать внутри `try/catch`, как обычно... тут никакой специфики из-за `onCreate` нет